# Why does this C code compile? C struct typdef

Tags: c, compiler-construction, struct

I wrote the following program:

```
typedef struct blahblah {
    int x;
    int y;
} Coordinate;

int main () {
   Coordinate p1;
   p1.x = 1;
   p1.y = 2;

   //blah blah has not been declared as a struct, so why is it letting me do this?
   struct blahblah p2;
   p2.x = 5;
   p2.y = 6; 
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

Comment: I don't quite understand. `struct blahblah` certainly *has* been declared as a struct, it's right at the top of your example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You said:

> blah blah has not been declared as a struct,

Actually, it has:

```
typedef struct blahblah {
    int x;
    int y;
} Coordinate;
```

This is both a typedef `Coordinate`, and a definition of `struct blahblah`. What the definition says is:

- define a data-type called  `struct blahblah`
- It has two members, `int x` and `int y`.
- Also, make a type definition called `Coordinate` that is equivalent to `struct blahblah`

Answer (score 2):

Your struct declaration is equivalent to

```
struct blahblah {
    int x;
    int y;
};
typedef struct blahblah Coordinate;
```

Since this creates two names for the struct type (`struct blahblah`) and `Coordinate`, both type names are permissible for declaring variables.

Answer (score 2):

`typedef` defines a new user-defined data type but **DOES NOT invalidate the old definition**. For example `typedef int INT` will not invalidate `int`. Likewise your `blahblah` is still a valid defined structure! And Coordinate is just a new type!

Answer (score 0):

You declared blahblah as a struct in your typedef. A typedef is simply an easy way of referencing struct blahblah. But struct blahblah exists and that's why you can give it a typedef.

Answer (score 0):

typedef is used to create an alias of one type to another.  You're actually declaring the 'struct blahblah' in the typedef itself.  It's a bit confusing but as @Timothy and others note it's a valid definition.